# Writing The EXpression in SSRS To Display any one gender based on condition

Tags: reporting-services

i would like to display 'his' if the sex field is male and want to display 'her' if the sex field is female...how would i write the expression for this condition in SSRS reports

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `Switch()` or `IIf()`. I would recommend Switch() because I think it's easier to expand if you later need to deal with scenarios other than just "his" or "her", and it means you don't accidentally show something if the sex is NULL or an empty string or something.

Basically Switch() takes any even number of parameters, where the first in each pair is a condition, and the second is the data to return if the condition evaluates to true. You can use this to check the contents of your sex field and return his or her;

```
=Switch(Fields!sex.Value = "male", "his", Fields!sex.Value = "female", "her")
```

Comment: tnk u for your rply:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IIF` operator to get what you want. Set the expression as,

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!sex.Value),"defaultvalue",IIF(Fields!sex.Value = "male","His","Her"))
```

You should use the `IsNothing` to make sure to handle the `NULL` value from the database.